# Facebook's new fb:comments and FB.Event.subscribe 'comments.create' not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

Any help will be deeply appreciated as I've tried everything I can think of to get this going but to no avail.

I am using Facebook's updated (as of last week) fb:comments system but can not get the FB.Event.subscribe 'comments.create' and FB.Event.subscribe 'comments.remove' to work.

The page in question can be seen [here](http://recipetrees.com/recipes/2_plain-basmati-rice---rice-cooker).

I am initialising FB Asynchronously:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '191116444251564', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create', function (response) {
//  console.log('create', response);
  //got response.... now query FQL to return total number of post counts
  FB.api(
    {
      method: "fql.query",
      query: "SELECT count FROM comments_info WHERE xid='2_plain-basmati-rice---rice-cooker' and app_id='191116444251564'"
    },
    function(fql_response) {
      $j.post('/recipes/2_plain-basmati-rice---rice-cooker/commented', {count: fql_response[0].count});
    }
  );
});

FB.Event.subscribe('comments.remove', function (response) {
  //got response.... now query FQL to return total number of post counts
//  console.log('remove', response);
  FB.api(
    {
      method: "fql.query",
      query: "SELECT count FROM comments_info WHERE xid='2_plain-basmati-rice---rice-cooker' and app_id='191116444251564'"
    },
    function(fql_response) {
      $j.post('/recipes/2_plain-basmati-rice---rice-cooker/commented', {count: fql_response[0].count});
    }
  );
});

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//]]>
</script>
```

replacing both subscribe callbacks with a simple alert('tst') doesn't work.

I've tested the page using FB's linter and no errors show up for that particular page.

Again, my thanks to anyone whole could offer any tips or pointers.

Comment: I noticed that you're using `SELECT count FROM comments_info WHERE...`. Does that actually work to get the count of comments?

Comment: It used to when I was testing the code about a month or so ago... but a month is like 100 years in terms of Facebook's API so chances are it no longer works.... me? bitter? FU*%$*F!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Event.subscribe is a little shaky at the moment. I had similar code working last week (around March 8) but today (March 13) I noticed that the Event.subscribe is not firing. BTW, I think it is now supposed to be comment.create, not comments.create. That is what was working for me.

Comment: Thanks Jan.

I see FB have updated their FB.Event.Subscribe docs from comments.create to comment.create.

Good to know that it wasn't just me doing something stupid!

Answer (score 0):

Unreliable sources say Facebook's FQL is going to be updated soon to accommodate functions for the new comment system... We're all waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You read Facebook's documentation? That's a big mistake unfortunately.
Try with comments.add instead of comments.create...

Comment: Thanks Fabrice.... that's what I had initially before the new comments plugin went live last week. Will test.

Answer (score 0):

It is comment.create, that should work.